# como cambiar el nombre con el que la aplicacion se instala en el telefono

Tags: android, android-studio

queria saber si se puede cambiar el nombre con el que la aplicacion se instala en el telefono. El nombre publico digamos.

He probado a cambiar el nombre de la carpeta, del paquete, y el que aparece en `settings.gradle` pero nada funciono.
un saludo.

Comment: Hola guillan, he encontrado esta otra pregunta similar que quizás te ayude [Change app name per gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785270/how-to-change-app-name-per-gradle-build-type). Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes realizar definiendo el nombre en el atributo [`android:label`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element?hl=es-419#label) dentro de `<application` de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
   ...
   ...
   android:label="Mi Aplicaciòn"
   ...
   ...
```

no es necesario cambiar el "package name" de la aplicaciòn.

Answer (score 0):

También si quieres cambiar el nombre en X activity exacto usa después del Oncreate en tu Activity :

```
TuActivity.this.setTitle("My aApp");
```